# Creating a Geospatial Index on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I am using the Geospatial Feature of MongoDB and my typical document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574ebe5f9985eb31a9bdbe39"),
    "geoareaName" : "GEOAREA2",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    13.870663396091308,
                    3.481292724609375
                ],
                [
                    13.875996314658366,
                    3.482236862182617
                ],
                [
                    13.872746581997381,
                    3.484210968017578
                ],
                [
                    13.871829982503106,
                    3.484961986541748
                ],
                [
                    13.870663396091308,
                    3.481292724609375
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "color" : "#ff0000",
    "_version" : 4,
    "active" : false
}
```

and then there are some point locations which I query using the `$geoIntersects` keyword and it works like a charm. However, to optimally use the geospatial feature of mongo I want to put indexes around the location.

Can someone please suggest what should be the correct approach for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a **[2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)** on `loc`.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

It's pretty basic but it works great!